# Image is not displayed in PDF

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I am using **wkhtmltopdf convert** to convert HTML to PDF.

My image tag contain src from PHP file because we generate a graph and display it on the page.

My image tag looks like this:

`img src="/PresentationLayer/GetChart.php?&amp;type=PNG&amp;img=bop1&amp;id=mem1i21niqlsrha063vrbmk7t551f60c2597832"`

Image are displayed in HTML but is not in PDF. Please provide some suggestion for that.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion: put a absolute image url in the src to see if it is your pdf generator problem or something else

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same issue with `<img>`s not displaying. My [rather hacky] solution was:

```
div.logo
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 171px;
}
```

```
<div class="logo" style="background-image: url('path/to/img.png')">&nbsp;</div>
```